# Process each item in array with is data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for a way to send to "script.js" file a unique id each item from array, so that i can process data each item individuall

```
<script href="script.js"></sciprt> 
    script.js: 
    $(function(){ 
       $('#box').append( "<p>Box 1</p>" );
    }

    foreach($items as $item){
      echo '<div id="box"></div>';
    }
```

now i got this out put:

```
<div id="box">box 1</div>
<div id="box">box 1</div>
```

i need this output (from script file):

```
<div id="box">box 1</div>
<div id="box">box 2</div>
```

Comment: `id` is meant to be unique to each element. And all you need to do is, declare a variable outside the function giving it an initial value, use that variable in place of the number and keep incrementing.

Comment: this is i know :), but how can i send the id to external file like script.js?

Comment: @user3289059 try some thing like `echo 'var window.BOXID = 0';` and from you js file access the variable by `window.BOXID`.

Comment: @user3289059 You can simply declare the variable in `<script></script>` tags **before** calling your `script.js`. It would be accessible to your .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and from what I've concluded is that, you are trying to get server side information (PHP) to client side (JS).

```
$i = 0;

    foreach($items as $item)
    {

    echo '<div class="box" id="box_'.$i.'"></div>';
    $i = $i + 1

    }
```

Then client side with JS:

```
    function example()
    {

     $('.box').each(function(){
        var id_num = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
       //Do something with id_num here

     });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($items as $i=>$item){
  echo '<div id="box'.$i.'"></div>';
}
```

where `$i` is your own id for array elements.

**UPD**

In **script.js**:

```
$(function(){ 
    var i=0;
    while($('#box'+i))
    {
        $('#box'+i).append( "<p>Box "+(i+1)+"</p>" );
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: See **UPD** or like Grimbode write.